# Nginx Reverse Proxy Not sending request upstream

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a nginx reverse proxy to terminate https for my java service. I have my nginx server block set up like so:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8090$request_uri;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        return 404;
}
```

My request is as follows: https://example.com/hello?teststring=test
Currently the server is returning the nginx 404 page. I know it is making it into this block because when I changed the return 404 to return 302 https://google.com when I made the request it went to google in my browser rather than returning the teststring to my browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want redirect all https traffic to http://localhost:8090$request_uri  you don't need return anything in server block. Just remove that "return", reload nginx and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I have the "return 404;" at the end of my block and since there is no 301 or 302 redirect in my block it was sending the traffic to my upstream server but then getting to the return statement and then returning a 404 regardless of the validity of my request. I fixed this just be removing the "return 404". Comment if I should be keeping some kind of return statement.